# How to add .app (app part) into a share point page using powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app

I have an App which is already deployed into SharePoint site. I want to add that .app file into a SharePoint page using powershell script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot directly exact the WebPart file from the .APP File. Hence, during the development time, before the deployment package, we need to add the AppParts manually to the screen. Then export the WebPart and save the AppParts as .WebPart Files

Refer below for more details:
http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Add-AppParts-to-Publishing-Pages-in-SharePoint-2013-using-PowerShell